# How can I group adjacent columns of a pandas dataframe into groups of three?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  

 q  w  e  r  t  y  u  i  o   v
 p  a  s  d  f  g  h  j  k  b

I would like to form three groups
Group 1 = columns 2,3,4
Group 2 = columns 5,6,7
Group 3 = columns 8,9,10
```

How can i do this using pandas groupby ? The actual dataframe has about 200 hundred such rows that are named as "2000-01,2000-02,2000-03,2000-04,2000-05    2000-06,2000-07 ... 2015-11,2015-12,2016-01,2016-02,2016-03,2016-04,2016-05,2016-06,2016-07,2016-08" and I want to get the average of each quarter

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Alongside what sammy mentioned, can you add the logic behind grouping? or do you want a hardcoded answer? and what about columns 1, 10?

Comment: I want a general solution that can work on 200 columns that are numbered as follows 2000-01 2000-02 2000-03 2000-04 2000-05 2000-06 2000-07

Comment: @meerakapoor can u tell us that do u want to divide them into groups with length 3 or what?

Comment: @Dotizo yes that is what i want

Comment: I have to calculate the average price of each quarter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: @yatu is it better now ?

Comment: Please, share a sample of the actual data and the expected output

Comment: @yatu okay will do

Comment: @meerakapoor i tried a new way for an unknown numbers of columns in my update solution. check it out and let me know if you have been passed your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need `groupby`.

If you are not emphasizing on `groupby`, I believe you can do something like this (`df` is your dataframe variable):

```
group1 = df[["2","3","4"]]
group2 = df[["4","5","6"]]
group3 = df[["7","8","9"]]
```

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned there is an unknown number of this dataframe's columns so i prefer to update my code:

```
#df is the dataframe variable
i = 1
columnsList = []
finalList   = []
for column in df.columns:
    
    if(i%3 ==0):
        columnsList.append(column)
        group         = df[columnsList]
        finalList.append(group)
        del columnsList[:]
    else:
        columnsList.append(column)
    i += 1
```

Now just choose nth element (`n = i+1` and `i` is the index) of `finalList` as your nth group and do the process.ta-da!